# Automation using selenium, unable to search within lists of different versions

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I wanted to search for a particular version of seldon-core (1.7.0) ( https://pypi.org/) . I have reached (using selenium) till the release history page(https://pypi.org/project/seldon-core/#history) but not able to search for particular version (1.7.0).

I wanted to search that whole list(all versions are contained inside the list) for a version match.
PS: the list has div id as "history" and further it has subclasses in which version number is mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search for a particular version of seldon-core e.g. `1.7.0` within [seldon-core . PyPI History](https://pypi.org/project/seldon-core/#history) page you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631116/python-selenium-wait-for-several-elements-to-load/64770041#64770041) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://pypi.org/project/seldon-core/#history")
  text = "1.7.0"
  if(text in element.text for element in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.release__version")))):
      print("Version found")
  else:
      print("Version not found")
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Version found
  ```

---

### Update

If you want to search a list for a version match you can use:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://pypi.org/project/seldon-core/#history")
  versions_search = ["1.8.2", "1.9.2", "1.7.0"]
  versions_available = [element.text for element in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.release__version")))]
  if any(x in versions_search for x in versions_available):
      print("Version match found")
  else:
      print("Version match not found")
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Version match found
  ```

Comment: Thanks, I also wanted to click on that element (for single version case) if it existed. Is there any way?